# Confusion in understanding the working of FeatureUnions (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am learning about pipelines and feature unions in pandas. I understand the working of pipelines, which help in applying a series of transformations to a given dataset. But, I am confused regarding feature unions. I have read the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) where it says that the transformers are applied in parallel and the result is then concatenated.

I have a doubt in this, if we apply all the transformers to the entire dataset or different transformers to selected features only? If to the entire dataset the how do we concatenate the result? Also, are there any general use cases where I should use FeatureUnion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FeatureUnion` is used when you want to apply different kind of transformation to the features. It may be that for the same set of features you want to apply multiple type of transformations, and want to use the combination of all those transformation as your new features.

The explanation in [the documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#featureunion-composite-feature-spaces) should give you some idea.

I think you are confused after reading the current version documentation. Previously `FeatureUnion` used to do whats `ColumnTransformer` is doing in version 0.20. Compare the latest example here:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer.html

with the previous version documentation here:

- http://scikit-learn.org/0.19/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

You will notice the similarities.

You can try searching on Stackoverflow to find different use-cases of FeatureUnion. If still not satisfied, please feel free to ask more specific questions. It may be helpful to know what you want to do with your dataset.

**Update for comment**:

Number of features may increase or decrease. `FeatureUnion` will not preserve your original features if you dont keep them in the transformation.

Take this example:

```
estimators = [('linear_pca', PCA(n_components=5)), 
              ('kernel_pca', KernelPCA(n_components=10))]
combined = FeatureUnion(estimators)
```

Assuming your original data has 100 features. The above FeatureUnion will return only 15 new features.

- PCA will get all your 100 features and transform them to keep only 5 components, which will be returned to the FeatureUnion.
- Similarly, KernelPCA will also get all your 100 features and keep 10 components in the transformed data.
- FeatureUnion will then just concatenate those 5 and 10 features to return 15 new features to you.

Comment: As you mentioned, `for the same set of features you want to apply multiple type of transformations, and want to use the combination of all those transformation as your new features`, this will give me multiple dataframes with the same size as my raw one. How do I combine these to again have a dataframe of same size? Do we take intersections or select the most relevant feature by training with the model?

Comment: @bkshi FeatureUnion will combine them and give you a single array. The number of rows will be same, but the columns will be depending on the transformations.

Comment: Does this mean, the number of features in my data increase depending on different transformations that I apply on them?

Comment: @bkshi I have added the explanation in the comments.

Comment: Hello @VivekKumar, thanks for the great explanation above, just one question, what would be the difference of doing, for example, data imputer or a data scaling in a FeatureUnion or in a pipeline? That is not so clear to me

Comment: @FelipeArayaOlea I am not entirely sure of what you are asking. FeatureUnion (ColumnTransformner in newer versions) is used when for the same input X, you need to  have different processing and then combine the new made features (after processing). If not and doing just the scaling on all of the input, then no need to put it into the FeatureUnion. Please elaborate more clearly on what you want to do?